# Error :couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I have a problem when server start mongodb

> user@-VirtualBox:~$ mongo 
>   MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
>   connecting to: test Sun May  8 22:10:13.641 Error: couldn't connect to
>   server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145 exception:
>   connect failed

how resolved this problem ?

Comment: have you started mongodb service? if not please start it using service mongod start

Comment: user@-VirtualBox:~$ sudo start mongod
mongod start/running, process 9129
user@-VirtualBox:~$ sudo status mongod
mongod stop/waiting               I did not understand why it is closed??

Comment: do a sudo ps -ef | grep mongod and kill all the processes listed there and then a fresh start

Comment: that's what I                                                                                   user@-VirtualBox:~$ sudo ps -ef | grep mongod
user  9160  8986  0 22:24 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongod                  after another server start the same result of the last command

Comment: Here the contents of the file mongodb.con  # mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
 

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

Comment: the problem is solved through this link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/147135/how-can-i-uninstall-mongodb-and-reinstall-the-latest-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Looking into MongoDB log file, located in `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, explained the reason - in my case it was:

```
ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your port is already in use, try changing the port number other than 27017.
Then start first with 'mongod' command which keep running in background after than run 'mongo'.
this one worked for me on my mac

> Find "usr/local/etc" dir
>   In "etc" folder find "mongod.conf"
>   In the file I had to set the bindIp configuration item to 0.0.0.0, i changed port to 27020

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27020
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

run following:

> mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

then run following by opening new tab in terminal:

```
> mongo --port 27020
```

Hope this works for you.